# Big union of big union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I understand that: $ x\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ can be expressed in the following way $x\in \{A\in X_i|i\in I\}$. Now, I'm trying to make the same analogy for the following $x\in \displaystyle \bigcup_{I\in J}\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$.

My attempt is the following:

I will call $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ as $T_I$. So $x\in \displaystyle \bigcup_{I\in J}T_I$. Then $x\in\{B\in T_I|I\in J\}$=$\{B\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i|I\in J\}=\{B\in \{A\in X_i|i\in I\}|I\in J\}$.

It doesn't seem correct to me, but even if it were it seems like a bit of a strange notation to me.

Comment: $x\in \{A\in X_i|i\in I\}$ is a strange and dubious notation in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i = \{x : \exists i \in I,~ x \in X_i\} $$ and $$\displaystyle \bigcup_{I\in J}\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i= \{x : \exists I \in J,~ \exists i \in I,~ x \in X_i\}.$$

Comment: I have another question, is the second expression an already established definition or can it be deduced from the first expression?

Comment: It follows from the first definition. To see this, set X_I = union of the X_i over all i in I.